# Intersection of Set A and a set containing empty set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Give set $A = \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\} , \{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$, is $\{\emptyset\} \cap A = \{\emptyset\}$ or just $\emptyset$?  I understand that $\emptyset \cap A = \emptyset$ (and why this is true), but I'm thrown off by the repeated nesting of empty sets within sets.

Given that, I am under the impression that $\emptyset \cup A = A =\{\emptyset\} \cup A$.  Is this also true?

Comment: @amWhy: $\{\emptyset\} \cap A$ is the set of all $x$ s.t. $x \in \{\emptyset\}$ and $x \in A$. $\emptyset \in \{\emptyset\}$ and $\emptyset \in A$; so $\emptyset \in \{\emptyset\} \cap A$. Therefore, $\{\emptyset\} \cap A \neq \emptyset$; because by definition of $\emptyset$,  $\forall x: x \notin \emptyset$. Instead, $\{\emptyset\} \cap A = \{\emptyset\}$

Comment: @amWhy surely that makes $ \{\emptyset\} \cap A = \{\emptyset\} $, not $ \emptyset $  ?

Comment: @amWhy FWIW, exactly this is covered in the first couple of pages of a degree level text on set theory I happened to be reading the other night.  A set containing the empty set is not an empty set, and you've contradicted yourself.  If the _element shared_ is $ \emptyset $ then the **set** containing that **element** is $ \{ \emptyset \} $, and not $ \emptyset $ itself.

Comment: Oh look, @amWhy deleted all their comments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general,

$$\emptyset \cup S = S \not=\{\emptyset\} \cup S$$

Note that in our case, $A =  \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\} , \{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$, $A $ is a *set* of **sets** and $\emptyset $ is just a set with nothing. $B = \{\emptyset\}$ is also a set of sets, but happens to only contain the empty set. Then we have

$$A = \{\emptyset, B, \{B\}\} $$

And thus $A \cap B = B = \{\emptyset\}$ given that $B \subset A $.

Also, for the $A $ given, $A \cup B = A $ **only because** $B \subset A$. There are plenty of sets $S $ where $S \cup B \not= S$.

Comment: IMHO, your first line would be clearer if it included the caveat that $ S \not= \{ \emptyset \} \cup S $ **unless** $ \emptyset \in S $

Comment: which is itself just a special case of $ S \not= \{ x \} \cup S $ unless $ x \in S $

Answer (score 4):

"Nothing exists" is one (tongue in cheek) way of thinking about [the axiom of the empty set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_empty_set).

The empty set $\emptyset$ exists by fiat; which is to say (either directly as an axiom or derived from other axioms), $\exists \emptyset : \forall x, x \notin \emptyset$.

Once we have **any** set $x$, we have rules by which we can prove the existence of other sets; such as the set $\{x\}$ whose only element is $x$, and so on. $\emptyset$ is no different in this respect; it is a set, and we have rules that show how to construct other sets from sets whose existence we have already proven.

The union of two sets $A$ and $B$ is a set with the property $\forall x: (x \in A \cup B \iff x \in A \lor x \in B)$. So thinking about $\emptyset \cup A$, we are talking about a set:

$$\forall x: (x \in \emptyset \cup A \iff x \in \emptyset \lor x \in A)$$

But by **definition**, it can never be true that $x \in \emptyset$; so the above boils down to:

$$\forall x: (x \in \emptyset \cup A \iff x \in A)$$

or in other words (see [axiom of extensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality)); $\emptyset \cup A = A$.

On the other hand there does exist some set $x$ s.t. $x \in \{\emptyset\}$; namely, the set $x = \emptyset$.  So when we consider $\{\emptyset\} \cup A$,we are talking about the set:

$$\forall x: (x \in \{\emptyset\} \cup A \iff x \in \{\emptyset\} \lor x \in A)$$

Thus $\{\emptyset\} \cup A$ is not necessarily equal to $A$; because (depending on $A$) we might not have $\emptyset \in A$, but we do have $\emptyset \in \{\emptyset\}$; and therefore $\emptyset \in \{\emptyset\} \cup A$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\emptyset=${ } which contains no element while the set $X=${$\emptyset$} is non-empty containing an element $\emptyset$.

{$\emptyset$}$\cap A$ represents the intersection of $X$ with $A$ which is clearly the set $X$ itself as $X\subset A$

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused between subsets and members of a set.
$\emptyset$ is a subset of every set but it is not necessarily a member of every set but in your question set A has $\emptyset$ as a member and the set$\{\emptyset\}$ also has $\emptyset$ as a member, as they have only one member in common $A \cap \{\emptyset\}=\{ \emptyset\}$ because $A \cap B$ is the set of all common members of A and B.

Let $A \cap {\emptyset}=B$ then B is the set of all common members in set A and ${\emptyset}$ as they have no common members their intersection B is  the empty set, hence $A \cap {\emptyset}=B={\emptyset}$.
 yes $\emptyset \cup A = A =\{\emptyset\} \cup A$ is a true statement but it's not true for any set A in general.

Comment: I think your first sentence is exactly correct.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=\{0,1,2\}$ and $B=\{0\}$. Now your question is (up to renaming symbols) if $A\cap B=B$ or $A\cap B =\emptyset$, which I think you can answer with ease.